# function to check if there are enough units in stock to meet request

Tags: java

I'm new to programming and I am making an electronic store in java which requires a product class.

The function I'm struggling with:
double sellUnits(int amount) – simulates selling amount units. If there are
enough units in stock to meet the request, the quantity attributes must be
updated appropriately and the total revenue for selling (revenue = units *
price) should be returned. If there are not enough units in stock, no sale
should take place and 0.0 should be returned.

I'm not quite sure how to check if there are enough units in stock to meet the request. I'm selling desktops, laptops, and fridges, and all of them will be contained in a products array. What I have right now under the function is just a placeholder, I'm not sure how to approach this issue.

```
public class Product {
      double price;
      int stockQuantity;
      int soldQuantity;

  public Product(double p, int stkquantity){
    price = p;
    stockQuantity = stkquantity;

  }


  public double sellUnits(int amount){
    if(balance <= amount){
      amount -= balance;
      return true;
   }
    return 0.0;    
  }

}
```

Comment: an `if` statement is the right approach. The condition must express "enough units in stock" and then do ... else do ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sell function you return to different types. That causes an error.
You also need to initiate the sold qunatitiy.
This should do it.

```
public class Product {
        double price;
        int stockQuantity;
        int soldQuantity = 0;

    public Product(double p, int stkquantity){
        price = p;
        stockQuantity = stkquantity;
    }

    public double sellUnits(int amount){
        if(stockQuantity >= amount){
            stockQuantity -= amount;
            soldQuantity += amount;
            return price * amount;
        }
        return 0.0;    
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! I was wondering if it should be stockQuantity >= amount instead because I thought <= would mean the user is trying to buy more than the store has?

Comment: Do you really think you help a newcomer best by giving away the complete solution?

Answer (score 0):

Think about how you would do this manually. Imagine you owned a store, and you received an order. You want to know if you can actually perform the order.

Well, you either already know you have 10 laptops available, or you would go count them. It's easier to keep a post-it note near the register saying "10 left" and then replace it with "8 left" when two are sold, although you need to make sure you keep it up to date.

Your program is going to work the same way.

So using your class above, your sellUnits method needs to see if you're trying to sell more than you have. if (amount > stockQuantity) then someone is trying to buy more than you have. Return 0 because you want to say, "We can't sell that many, but we have 8 instead of 10". Or whatever.

But if you have enough, then you subtract from stockQuantity the number you just sold, increment the soldQuantity, and return quantity * price.

Almost always, when figuring out basic algorithms, you can reliably think, "How would I do this manually myself". That will clue you in quite a bit.